# Error when showing Youtube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-api

I got this error while showing a YouTube video. Does any one have solution for this? The error is:

> Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube: insecure reporting URL for secure page at character position 22. The default protections will be applied.

Comment: i followed this link : http://jsfiddle.net/slabmedia/n8x9oadh/

Comment: Can you update the question with your version of the code. Also please put the information in your comment, into the question. If it's relevant to the question it should be there, not in the comments.